# Installshield sideload: app not start after install

Tags: windows-8.1, installshield, sideloading, appx

I have a problem with a Windows 8.1 app that I want to deploy by sideloading.

I installed InstallShield premier to test it's feature, and generated an installation package that contains appx file and a test certificate file created by visual studio (associated in installshield project properties).

I need to enable app distribution in group policy settings to install.

After app correctly installs on system, i found it in start menu, but when i try to run the app, windows shows a popup that says "there is a problem with this app, contact administrator".

Target system is a Windows 8.1 Pro 32 bit PC.

Id there any other settings that I must enable on target system before install the app with InstallShield?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple requirements for sideloading to work, [documented on technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852635.aspx#SideloadingRequirements), which I've summarized here:

1. Activate the sideloading product key on the device OR join the device to an Active Directory domain (except for certain embedded devices which do not require either of these).
2. Enable the Allow all trusted applications to install Group Policy setting.

Since you don't mention it, I'm going to guess that your machine has neither the sideloading product key nor a domain membership (nor is it one of the special embedded cases), so that's where I'd start.

For more troubleshooting ideas, see some blogs like [Sideloading Store Apps to Windows 8.1 Devices](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/micham/archive/2014/05/30/sideloading-store-apps-to-windows-8-1-devices.aspx) or [How Do I Deploy a Windows 8 App to Another Device for Testing?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2012/11/05/how-do-i-deploy-a-windows-8-app-to-another-device-for-testing.aspx)